# Apache Cayenne performQuery result List cast

Tags: list, orm, generic-list, apache-cayenne

I am using 3.0 Apache Cayenne, 
how can I ommit @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") in Eclipse for such simple code:

```
public List<Some> getSomes() {
    SelectQuery select = new SelectQuery(Some.class);
    List<Some> somes = dbContext.performQuery(select);
    return somes;
}
```

I cannot find any solution, is it because (I think) performQuery retuns an object List ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generics in queries is a feature available since Cayenne 3.2. In 3.2 you'd run queries like this, getting type-safe results:

```
SelectQuery<Some> select = new SelectQuery<>(Some.class);
List<Some> somes = dbContext.select(select);
```

But there will be 'unchecked' warnings if you are using 3.0. There's no way around this.